# Git rollback to previous checkout

Tags: git

I've cloned some project from github, to my project, all works good, I'm happy.

But after some git pulls I receive some conflicts in my project with new commits of upstream project.

I want to rollback to previous checkout, but i don't know which stable checkout was previous in my project.

How I can know it and rollback to previous stable (for me) project checkout? I understand that in perspective more correct way to fix my conflicts with upstream repo, but sometimes i just need rollback to previous version, to get time for fixing problem.

Comment: it's not clear to me if you know how to checkout a previous version? If not see http://stackoverflow.com/q/1223354/11343.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a command/script you can execute and which would illustrate a "stable point" (ie something working, as opposed to the current state where it is not working), then you can consider a **`git bisect`** command.
See "[How to use git bisect?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4713088/how-to-use-git-bisect)".

That would help you isolate the last commit where "it was working".

Comment: Also seems a bit over the top seeing as there was a known point recently.

Comment: @CharlesB Sure, hence the link explaining how to use it. Anyway, if the commit is fairly recent, the other answers seem more appropriate.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It was realy that i need.

Answer (score 1):

`git reflog` should tell you the order of operations, most recent first. Look for the commit ID that was operated on before your first pull/merge; `checkout` or `reset --hard` to that.

Answer (score 0):

Have you already commited the merge? If not, just `git reset --hard` and you're back to the state before you issued `git pull`. Otherwise, `git reset --hard HEAD^` (if the merge was the last commit) does the trick, since git will by default always pick the first parent of a merge commit, which is your branch. If in doubt, you can always use e.g. `gitk` to inspect the situation and find the last commit on your branch, copy its SHA1 hash and revert to that.