# Which commit made a file executable

Tags: git

I have an executable file in a git repository.

**How do I find out which commit made that file executable?**

I tried `git log file.txt` but that does not show changes in file modes and searching man pages and google was fruitless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
git log -p file.txt | grep --before-context 7 "old mode"
```

(If your commit text is multiple lines long, increase the before context line option so it includes the commit ID)

The file mode change include "old mode" and "new mode" in the log, which is how this works.

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly what I have been looking for. It's a personal pet peeve of mine when someone accidently makes something executable.

Answer (score 1):

`git log --raw` (or `git whatchanged`, which skips merges as well) extracts the modes:

```
:100644 100644 bcd1234... 0123456... M file0
```

The first octal number is the old mode, the second is the new.  If the file became executable the old mode will end with `644` and the new one with `755`.  A regular file has mode `100` before the `644` or `755`.  So this will find it quickly:

```
git log --raw -- path/to/file | grep -B 1 '^:100644 100755 '
```

If there are multiple transitions from non-executable to executable, this will find all of them.

Answer (score 0):

Try using git bisect [How to use git bisect?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4713088/how-to-use-git-bisect)

It can help you search by picking commits in the most optimal way. You will start by picking two commits, one where it doesn't work and one where it does. After that git will give you a commit, you test if it works and respond accordingly. After a few tries you will find the right commit.