# Searching old commits

Tags: git, tortoisegit

Is there a way to search for old code in `Tortoise Git`? For example, let's say I want to look at an old commit with some old code (that has since been changed), but I'm not sure which file it's in, and it's such a large project that manually scrolling through the commits is super tedious. Is there a way that I can enter in some key words and Tortoise Git will search through all files and across all commits for those key words?

Thanks!

Update: The closest I can get is to right-click > Git History and then do a search there for the key words, but that will only search one commit at a time, so you have to scroll from commit to commit until you see your keywords highlighted in yellow. Better than nothing I suppose, but still tedious. I'm hoping there's a way to search key words across all commits that someone might know of.

Comment: It is not recommended to put tags in the title - I took out Tortoise Git.

Comment: I think you're looking for `grep`, but I have no clue if your GUI has that.

Comment: `git log` has a `-G` option that searches for additions or deletions of a regex

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `git bisect`. Its exactly what bisect is for. Finding old code without knowing where or when it was created/modified.

[How to use git bisect?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4713088/how-to-use-git-bisect)

Comment: I wasn't previously aware of git bisect so thank you for bringing that up, although I don't think it solves my original problem. I may not be searching for a bug that breaks my code...I'm looking for some code and/or comments that ran fine and has since been changed, but I want to now reference it. But I can't easily find it among many files and many commits.

Comment: This is why you are using bisect. run a scrip to find the code you need