# How to use julia package at a certain commit?

Tags: julia

A new version of a julia package causes a problem in my project. I could use `Pkg.pin` to use the package at some version and I could use `Pkg.checkout` to use the package in a certain github branch, but how to use the package at a certain github commit? So I could find out which commit actually causes the issue in my project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every Julia package is just a git repo, you could always do source code management stuff using git from the command line, and use some full-featured git commands like `git bisect` to find out that commit.

X-ref: [How to use git bisect?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4713088/how-to-use-git-bisect)

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I tried the git bisect command, and it seems really useful!!

Answer (score 3):

To answer the original question, we can add a package at a specified commit, by specifying the commit-sha1 as follows:

```
(@v1.6) pkg> add Example#commitSHA1
```

by replacing the `commitSHA1` with the commit-sha1 of the required commit of the package.

See the [Pkg docs](https://pkgdocs.julialang.org/v1/managing-packages/) for more.