# Bisecting faulty commits

Tags: git, git-bisect

Hope you are doing well!

i have a query on how to automate git bisect. currently we are manually finding the faulty commit in bunch of commits manually given git bisect commands. Is there any python script or any bash script?

as am very new to scripting :)

like

git bisect start
git bisect bad
git bisect good "commit sha value"
run the test

and on failed scenario it should take command git bisect bad
and on pass scenario it takes git bisect good

this above should continue until it finishes all the commits check.

your response is welcome Thank you in advance.

Comment: That's what `git bisect run` does.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/22592593/7976758

Comment: thanks not familiar with that i will check. more suggestions are welcome. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

First you have to write a script that returns 0 if and only if the checked commit is good. For example, the script can run the unit tests.

When you have this script (let's call it `check-app.sh`), place it in local your git repo and then run :

```
git bisect start <a-bad-revision> <a-good-revision>
git bisect run ./check-app.sh
```

Comment: okie, thanks for the info. do you have an example of such script which returns 0?

Comment: Yes, but it is very specific: if you code in Java with Maven, `mvn test` will return 0 if and only if all unit tests are ok. Clearly, writing the script is the essential part of the work.

Comment: Thanks, for the inputs,  but as am totally new to scripting, so was looking some initative, well i started reading some documents on python, as i have to write a git bisect automate code in python.