# How to see refs/bisect/bad?

Tags: git, git-bisect

Some [documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-bisect) for git-bisect says, "The reference `refs/bisect/bad` will be left pointing at that commit."  I'm not sure what a "reference" is.

How do I see what `refs/bisect/bad` refers to?

I checked [How to use git bisect?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4713088/how-to-use-git-bisect) but I don't think it explains how to see what `refs/bisect/bad` points to.

Answer (score 1):

To see what `refs/bisect/bad` points to, I was able to use the following command:

`git show-ref refs/bisect/bad`

I discovered this by searching google for "refs/bisect/bad" and I came across https://github.com/github/git-msysgit/blob/master/git-bisect.sh which uses `git show-ref`.  Then I reasoned that a "reference" could be a git concept, so I googled "how to see a git reference" and sure enough it gave me the documentation https://git-scm.com/docs/git-show-ref.

I hope this helps others searching for the same answer.

Comment: Or `git rev-parse` or `git show` or, well, pretty much *any* Git command will take `refs/bisect/bad` as an argument. You can shorten it to `bisect/bad` if you have no other higher-priority name that matches, but spelling out the full name always works.