# How to solve the following gem5 build error?

Tags: gcc, g++, gem5

I am firstly building gem5 on ubuntu18.04 using the command `"scons build/X86/gem5.opt"`. When it built `"X86/arch/X86/generated/inst-constrs.cc->o"` an unexpected error is raised, How should I solve this?

Beforehand, I met the error

> "unknown pseudo code"

I have found a feasible solution. That is to degrade gcc and g++ to 5 version. However, there is a new

> "unknown pseudo-op '.lbb366010'"

error raised.

```
{standard input}: Assembler messages:
{standard input}: 87979: Warning: end of file not at end of a line; newline inserted
{standard input}: 88437: Error: unknown pseudo-op '.lbb366010'
{standard input}: Error: open CFI at the end of ifle; missing .cif_endproc directive
```

Comment: Hi Henry, I have the following recommendations: 1) CC the mailing list as well for build failures 2) always give your gem5 git commit on all messages 3) add the key error message to the title on Stack Overflow / mailing list subject 4) try to debug it a bit yourself as well, and possibly send a patch, since build failures are the simplest problems to solve generally. This is an auto-generated file, so you will need to understand where the line comes from. 5) Learn how to use git bisect if it is too hard to debug yourself: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4713088/how-to-use-git-bisect