# scons: building terminated because of errors

Tags: gem5

I cloned this https://gem5.googlesource.com/public/gem5 and ran the scons build/X86/gem5.opt -j5 in the gem5 directory. I get

> scons: building terminated because of errors.

A snippet of the error log:

```
  In file included from build/X86/arch/x86/interrupts.hh:58,
                     from build/X86/arch/interrupts.hh:1,
                     from build/X86/cpu/base.hh:57,
                     from build/X86/mem/abstract_mem.cc:50:
    build/X86/arch/x86/intmessage.hh: In function 'Packet*    X86ISA::buildIntRequest(uint8_t, X86ISA::TriggerIntMessage)':
    build/X86/arch/x86/intmessage.hh:105:42: error: implicitly-declared 'constexpr BitfieldBackend::BitUnionOperators<X86ISA::BitfieldUnderlyingClassesTriggerIntMessage>::BitUnionOperators(const
    BitfieldBackend::BitUnionOperators<X86ISA::BitfieldUnderlyingClassesTriggerIntMessage>&)' is deprecated [-Werror=deprecated-copy]
      105 |                 sizeof(TriggerIntMessage));
```

Another snippet:

```
In file included from build/X86/cpu/base.hh:64,
                 from build/X86/mem/abstract_mem.cc:50:
build/X86/sim/insttracer.hh: In member function 'void Trace::InstRecord::setData(VecRegContainer<8>&)':
build/X86/sim/insttracer.hh:203:71: error: implicitly-declared 'constexpr VecRegContainer<8>::VecRegContainer(const VecRegContainer<8>&)' is deprecated [-Werror=deprecated-copy]
  203 |         data.as_vec = new ::VecRegContainer<TheISA::VecRegSizeBytes>(d);
```

Warnings:

```
MI_example-cache.sm:179: Warning: Non-void return ignored, return type is 'bool'
MI_example-cache.sm:181: Warning: Non-void return ignored, return type is 'bool'
MI_example-cache.sm:336: Warning: Non-void return ignored, return type is 'Tick'
MI_example-cache.sm:350: Warning: Non-void return ignored, return type is 'Scalar'
MI_example-cache.sm:354: Warning: Non-void return ignored, return type is 'Scalar'
MI_example-dir.sm:183: Warning: Non-void return ignored, return type is 'bool'
MI_example-dir.sm:398: Warning: Non-void return ignored, return type is 'Tick'
MI_example-dir.sm:402: Warning: Non-void return ignored, return type is 'Tick'
MI_example-dir.sm:482: Warning: Non-void return ignored, return type is 'Tick'
MI_example-dir.sm:277: Warning: Unused action: a_sendWriteBackAck, Send writeback ack to requestor
MI_example-dma.sm:189: Warning: Non-void return ignored, return type is 'Tick'
MI_example-dma.sm:193: Warning: Non-void return ignored, return type is 'Tick'
```

>
    git SHA: af8d107191cc69a77624e2af34f108dc9c1ff03f

```
OS: Archlinux 5.1.11-arch1-1-ARCH
```

It previously worked on my computer with the same procedure. It works on my other system(pc).

Comment: Thanks for the report, a few tips: 1) also provide your compiler / OS version 2) build failures are usually easy to debug and fix, have you tried? :-) 3) If it happens to not be easy, just git bisect it and email the mailing list CC the person who broke: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4713088/how-to-use-git-bisect

Comment: I have updated the original post to include OS version. All I have tried doing to fix is change the architecture, but to no avail. I will try emailing.

Comment: Mailing list thread: https://www.mail-archive.com/gem5-users@gem5.org/msg16629.html