# Can I use git to find which commit is needed to fix a branch?

Tags: git, git-branch, git-commit

I have a git tree which looks like this:

```
master (test passes)
|
|
|  stable (test fails)
|   |
|   /
+---
|
```

There is a test which fails when run against the `stable` branch, but passes when run against the `master` branch.  As it is a complicated multi-process test it's rather hard to debug.

Can I use git to find which commit from the master branch can be cherry-picked to the stable branch in order to fix the test?

There are many hundreds of commits on both branches so doing it manually would be painful.

Comment: `git bisect` may be of help

Comment: Sounds like this might be a good use case for [`git-bisect`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-bisect) -- [here is a good SO post about it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4713088/how-to-use-git-bisect).

Comment: I use `git bisect` frequently but I'm unclear how it is relevant to this.  How exactly would you use it?

Comment: Figure out if it was passing or failing at the point they split.  If it was passing, it was broken on `stable`-- if it was failing, it was fixed on `master`.  In the former instance, we would `bisect` between `stable` and point where they split to see at which point it started failing and fix it.  In the latter instance, we would `bisect` between `master` and where they split and find the commit at which the test began passing, and then `cherry-pick` that commit.  Keep in mind there's no guarantee here- if the history is complex or the fix spread over several commits it might not be possible.

Comment: @Rich What are you finding unsuitable about using git-bisect on this particular problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> There are many hundreds of commits on both branches so doing it manually would be painful.

This is a job for `git-bisect`.

Start the bisect, `git bisect start`.

You know it's failing on stable, mark it as bad. `git bisect bad stable`.

You know it's passing on master, mark it as good: `git bisect good master`

Bisect will now select a commit between the two and check it out. Run your test. If it passes, `git bisect good`. It it fails, `git bisect bad`.

Bisect will pick another commit. Do the same thing.

Repeat until Git finds the commit where it started failing. Because it is doing a [binary search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm), searching hundreds of commits should take about 20-30 commits. You can automate the process by writing a script to do the build and testing and passing it to `git bisect run my_script <args>`.

This depends on a single commit being the cause of the failure. If you have not been testing consistently during development there might be a newer commit which introduces the bug again (a regression). You may need to bisect again beginning with a newer "good" commit.

For more details, see the [`git-bisect` documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-bisect). They provide very clear instructions. Also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4713088/how-to-use-git-bisect).

Comment: I had absolutely no idea `git bisect` could be used like this, thanks!

Comment: @Rich This is all I've ever used `git bisect` for! I'm curious what you've been using it for?

Comment: Going back and forwards on the same branch.

Comment: @Rich And you didn't think it would work between branches. It will effectively check [`master...stable`](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitrevisions#_dotted_range_notations). That is, all commits reachable by master or stable, but not both.